# jquery how can i bind click event to string based elements?

Tags: jquery

i am making a loop, and getting the thumb image info, this is the code for that,

```
$.map(galImg, function ( val ,i ){
  // adding no.of li's
  thumList += '<li><img src='+val.thumb+'></li>';   
})

thumList += "</ul>"

// finally placed in to navi div.
navi.html(thumList);
```

Up to all works find. but what i am looking is, how can i add the click event to each of this `<li>`'s? while i make (Because once the user click on the `<li>`'s i will get the index number and replace the slider accordingly.)

Comment: Add id's to the li elements being added to the `navi` element and set a `$('#li...').bind("click",function(){});` for each li

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It's really really hard to decipher what you are trying to say.

Comment: Simply select all `li` elements after you inserted them into the tree. Or create proper DOM elements, bind the handlers and insert them instead of using strings. @siidheesh: That's not really a good solution.

Comment: Note that the second line should be `thumList += '<li><img src="'+val.thumb+'"></li>';` (missing quotes)

Comment: The `li...` was just a placeholder for `#li1`, `#li2` etc. EDIT: OK i see your point, binding the `click` event to all the li elements is better

Comment: @siidheesh: Yes, I understand that, that's why it's not a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
navi.on('click', 'li', function(){
     alert( $(this).index() );
})
```

Comment: i aware about this. is there a way to attach click event while i create element?

Comment: @3gwebtrain: Yes, but why do you need to?

Comment: @3gwebtrain you can do '`<li onclick="somefunc()">...`', but your `somefunc` must be *globall*.

Comment: i don't want to keep a separate function to make the click. like shorten i am looking for. exp : $('<div />',{click:callFunction()}).appned('body'), like so!

Comment: So you'd rather have multiple separate functions than one single event? Note that you can do `navi.on( 'click', 'li', callFunction );` so you'll avoid the anonymous function.

Comment: @3gwebtrain You'd need to actually create the elements and append them, rather than simply creating a string of HTML, in order to bind the event handler to them individually. An alternative would be to store the index as a custom data attribute - something like `data-index` - of the individual elements, then reference that inside the callback of your event delegated using `.on()`.